# perl's Net::SMTP error setting 'to' value

Tags: perl, email, smtp

I'm trying to send an email using perl's Net::SMTP module, and I have some code that looks like this:

```
my $host = 'mail.server.com';

my $port = 00; 
my $smtp = new Net::SMTP("$host:$port") or return 1;

$smtp->mail('me@mail.com') or return 1;
$smtp->to('you@mail.com') or return 1;
$smtp->data() or return 1;
$smtp->datasend("Subject: blah, blah\n\n");
$smtp->datasend($message);

$smtp->dataend() or return 1;

$smtp->quit();
```

The problem is, it returns after trying to set the 'to' value, and I'm completely stumped as to why. Any ideas?

FWIW, I'm not a perl developer. I'm trying to cleanup the styling of the email, and just need to get it to send so I can evaluate my changes.

Comment: What error message(s) did you get?  You're using `strict` and `warnings`, right?

Comment: No errors or warnings thrown...

Comment: Replace the double-quotes in `$smtp->to("you@mail.com") or return 1;` with single quotes.  The interpreter thinks that `@mail.com` refers to an array while within double quotes (that interpolation isn't done within single quotes).

Comment: @JackManey: Same issue (I mis-copied the code originally)

Comment: Strange to do you use TCP port 0 for smtp !

Comment: Hmmm...replace `return 1;` with `die $!;` and see if the code spits out an error message.

Comment: Just filler. Didn't want to give out the actual port # (I know it's silly)

Comment: @JackManey: It just tells me the line it died on...

Comment: @danwoods - Hmmm...well, looking through the documentation, it seems as though there's a problem sending to the email address provided to the `to` method.  Can you send an email to that address manually (ie not via `Net::SMTP`)?

Comment: @JackManey: Yes. It's my email address :(

Comment: Just to make sure, you have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script, right?

Comment: @danwoods - If you are using `strict` and `warnings`, add the following just before the line where the script dies:  `use Data::Dumper;print Dumper($smtp) . "\n";` and tell us what the output is.

Comment: Issue seems to be that I couldn't send mail to external addresses!!! Once I changed the 'to' address to something local, it worked!!! Thanks so much for the debugging help!

Answer (score 1):

Chanhe your `To` part

```
$smtp->to('you@mail.com') or return 1;
```

**EDIT:**

In that case do some more changes and see if it helps

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $host = 'mail.server.com';
my $port = '00';

 my $smtp = new Net::SMTP($host:$port) or 
 die "Could not connect to server!\n" unless $smtp;

 //Rest of the code as is
```